# Airflow service host in docker-compose can't change time zone

Tags: docker-compose, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I would like to change the time zone of airflow from UTC to my current time zone(UTC+8 / Asia/Macau), and mark the DAG will run in Macau midnight not UTC midnight ( coz run in UTC midnight it make the data create time always be come previous day not today)

However I tried many method it still not work, I tried:

change DockerFile of the airflow project

```
# Airflow configurations
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=/app/project/brownian
ENV AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=False
ENV AIRFLOW__CORE__LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
ENV AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER=/app/project/brownian/brownian/dags
ENV AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__MIN_FILE_PROCESS_INTERVAL=60
ENV AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__SCHEDULER_MAX_THREADS=3
ENV AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TIMEZONE=Asia/Macau
ENV AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__DEFAULT_UI_TIMEZONE=Asia/Macau
```

Also tried to only change the DAG time znoe

```
tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Macau')


def localize_utc_tz(d):
    return tz.fromutc(d)

default_args = {
    "start_date":datetime(2020, 7, 20),
}

dag = DAG("scrap_sns", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="@daily",
          user_defined_filters={
              'localtz': localize_utc_tz,
          })
```

However both of them are not work, the time show in airflow still is UTC, and the DAG still run in UTC midnight not my position midnight.

And method I can try?

Or on the other hand, I just want the scheduler run in UTC+8 midnight, could I change the code/ something to achieve this target?

Comment: Hello, there is a good reason why airflow is in utc, the daylight saving time and anyother time change does not good to a datapipeline. You can just use the utc time so 16:00 UTC

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by add this environment "TZ: 'Asia/Tehran' " in the &airflow-common-env part in your docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    TZ: 'Asia/Tehran'
```

It works for me :)